# Add radio buttons to IF statement

Tags: java, swing

I have an `if` statement for a radio button and if clicked it will print to a file. The problem is that `if(mon1.isSelected())` that i have quite a few radio buttons and I want to add them in the `if` statement.

For Example:

```
if(mon1, mon2, mon3.isSelected())
```

Is this even possible to add more radio buttons like this?

**UPDATE**

Use an OR operator.

```
    if(mon1.isSelected() || mon2.isSelected()){
    bw.write("Monday 1pm"); bw.write(", ");
    bw.write("Monday 2pm"); bw.write(", ");
}
```

Now another problem is that even if one radio button is selected then both times are printed out. I want to be able to only print out the time based on which radio button is chosen.

Comment: do you want to check all elements has selected or ?

Comment: I want to add all my radio buttons in that one if statement. Otherwise I have to create an if statement for each button.

Comment: This method returns `boolean` so you can just combine it to `if(mon1.isSelected() && mon2.isSelected() && mon3.isSelected())`

Comment: *"Now another problem is that even if one radio button is selected then both times are printed out. I want to be able to only print out the time based on which radio button is chosen."* - Then use an `if-else` statement

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of buttons that may be logically grouped (for example, because they are inter dependent i.e. operations/checks are performed on all buttons every time), you may be interested to represent them as an `Array` of buttons.

This way, you can check button selection using a for loop as follows:

```
Button[] buttons;
....
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    if(buttons[i].isSelected()) {
        bw.write("Monday 1pm"); bw.write(", ");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i go about adding radio buttons to an array?

Comment: @DanTheMan Instead of declaring every individual button as a single variable, you can declare them as an Array. I guess that if you use an IDE, they will be created by default as single variables. You may need to change it manually.

Comment: If at most one button may be selected at any given time, you can break when you found the selected one. I updated my answer,

Comment: Okay, how do i create a button array and assign the buttons ive made to it?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. Correct syntax will be

```
if(mon1.isSelected() && mon2.isSelected() && mon3.isSelected()){

        // Three got selected. TODO

}
```

Or if you want to check any one of them got selected

```
if(mon1.isSelected() || mon2.isSelected() || mon3.isSelected()){

        // one of them got selected. TODO

}
```

**Update :**

Since you don't want to multiple writings ata at a time, try `if else`

```
if(mon1.isSelected()){

        // one got selected. TODO

} else if( mon2.isSelected()){

        // 2 got selected. TODO

}else if( mon3.isSelected()){

        // 2 got selected. TODO

}else {

      // please select 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use OR operator:

```
if(mon1.isSelected() || mon2.isSelected() || mon3.isSelected()){
      // Your code.
}
```

That's It.